# Track lack of update of a lot of value to fire alarm

Tags: java, timer

I need to find a way to track the fact a data haven't been updated for a specific amount of time to fire inactivity alarm.

My problem is that I can have a lot of data to track (for the moment a least 400 values) and that I don't want to create 400 timer that would be reseted on update.

The extra problem is that for each value, the inactivity timeout is not the same.

Is there a better way than fire 400 timer ?

Thanks.

Comment: Keep a "last updated" timestamp and compare now against then.

Comment: You mean using a thread looping on every value to check if it is outdated ? This will not be my case here, but what it we have a really big list of data to monitor ?

Comment: How many is "really big"?  I can create a `List` with 1,000,000 objects, and it only takes about 30ms on average to loop through the entire list and check all the dates.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.